# How do I create a secondary axis for a second function in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two functions. Both use the same x axis, but the values for the y axis are too high for one function compared to the other, so one function would just lie flat. How do I create a secondary y axis for the second function so that I can view both functions on one single plot?

This is my code:

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

g = 9.81
vo = 14.5
zo = 2.35
m = 7.257

sin = (vo/((2*((vo**2)+g*zo))**(1/2)))
alpha = math.asin(sin)
tan = math.tan(alpha)

z= []; x = []; E = []
for i in range(1000):
    x.append(i*(1/41))
    z.append(-(g/2)*((x[i]**2)/(vo**2))*(1+tan**2)+tan*x[i]+zo)
    E.append(m*g*z[i])
    if len(z)>=3:
        if z[-1]<=0 and z[-2]>0:
            x0 = (x[-1] + x[-2])/2
        if z[-2]>z[-1] and z[-2]>z[-3]:
            zmax=z[-2]
            xmax=x[-2]


fig = plt.figure()
plt.title("Wurf der Kugel")
plt.ylim(-1,700)
plt.xlim(0,25)
plt.xlabel("Distanz in m")
plt.ylabel("Hoehe in m")
dotx0=(x0,0)
dotmax=(xmax,zmax)
print("Die Wurfweite ist bei {}. Das Maximum ist bei {}".format(dotx0,dotmax))
plt.plot(x0,0,"o", markersize = 8, label=dotx0)
plt.plot(xmax,zmax,"o", markersize = 8, label=dotmax)
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend()
plt.plot(x,z)
plt.plot(x,E)

plt.show()
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [twinx](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=twinx#matplotlib.pyplot.twinx) to have two different y-scales in the same axes.

Just call plt.twinx() in between plot commands that have different scales.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-10,10,100)
y1 = x**2
# plot the first line
plt.plot(x,y1,'k') # large values
plt.ylabel('y1') # axis label on the left
# create a second y scale on the other side
plt.twinx()
y2 = 0.2*x
# now plot the second line on the second y-scale
plt.plot(x,y2,'r') # small values
plt.ylabel('y2') # axis label on the right
plt.show()
```

Comment: How do I use twinx in the code? Sorry, I'm a beginner!

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that!